# Error when trying to read excel file from web site

Tags: r

I'm trying to download the `xlsx` file that is available at the following url.  If you go to the website and click the link, it will download as a file on your computer.  However, I want to automate this process.  I have tried the following:

```
library(RCurl)
download.file("https://dshs.texas.gov/coronavirus/TexasCOVID19DailyCountyCaseCountData.xlsx", "temp.xlsx")
library(readxl)
tmp <- read_xlsx("temp.xlsx")
# Error: Evaluation error: error reading from the connection.
```

This method does download a temp.xlsx file to my drive.  However, if you try and manually click on it to open, excel fails to open it.  It knows it's size, but is unable to open.
.

```
readxl::read_xlsx("https://dshs.texas.gov/coronavirus/TexasCOVID19DailyCountyCaseCountData.xlsx")
    # Error: `path` does not exist: ‘https://dshs.texas.gov/coronavirus/TexasCOVID19DailyCountyCaseCountData.xlsx’
```

Both of these methods are my go-to for downloading excel files from websites.  Is there some specific reason why these methods don't work here?

Comment: wow - I did not know that for Windows.  Thanks.  Do you want to make it an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When downloading certain file formats on Windows you need to specify that it should be a binary rather than the (usual) default of a text transfer - from the `download.file()` documentation:

> The choice of binary transfer (mode = "wb" or "ab") is important on
> Windows, since unlike Unix-alikes it does distinguish between text and
> binary files and for text transfers changes \n line endings to \r\n
> (aka ‘CRLF’).
>
> On Windows, if mode is not supplied (missing()) and url ends in one of
> .gz, .bz2, .xz, .tgz, .zip, .rda, .rds or .RData, mode = "wb" is set
> such that a binary transfer is done to help unwary users.
>
> Code written to download binary files must use mode = "wb" (or "ab"),
> but the problems incurred by a text transfer will only be seen on
> Windows.

In this case so that the file is written correctly use:

```
download.file("https://dshs.texas.gov/coronavirus/TexasCOVID19DailyCountyCaseCountData.xlsx",
              "temp.xlsx", mode = "wb")
```